# Unable to mount Cypress component test for Angular components using Cypress 10.7.0

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to do component testing using Cypress component test runner. The web components are built using stencil. We compile the stencil components and create respective "Angular component" and import them into our projects. We are using a mono repository.

The folder structure is like this
**rootNode\packages\angular\cypress**

Under this angular folder, my spec file and the component will be available in the location **angular\src\app\components\button**

The component is as expected when launched in the angular app. When I tried to run the test for a component, I am getting the following error "**Cannot GET /__cypress/src/index.html**"

`cypress.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy-spec.ts",
    indexHtmlFile: "cypress/support/component-index.html",
    supportFile: "cypress/support/component.ts",
  },
});
```

`angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-example": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../target/www/playbook/angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "input": "../../node_modules/@nexus/core/dist/assets",
                "glob": "**/*",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-example:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-example:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-example:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-example:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular-example:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-example",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "angular-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext .ts ./src",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.9",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.6.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.9",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.3.9",
    "ng-packagr": "14.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.10.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^5.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^5.33.0",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "jasmine-core": "4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "9.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "html-loader": "3.1.2"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules",
    "node_modules",
    "../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`button.component.cy-spec.ts`

```
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component'

describe('ButtonComponent', () => {
    it('mounts', () => {
        cy.mount(ButtonComponent)
    })
})
```

`cypress\tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm having the same issue